# How to print the highest number in lists that are inside another list

Tags: python, list

I want to print the highest number from my list (`1231` here).
I tried doing this here (posted below), but that doesn't work. It just shows the highest total number for each element in my list, which is, obviously, not what I want.

```
list = [ [1,3,251], [2], [1231,52,22] ]

for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        print(max(list))
```

prints:

```
[1231, 52, 22]
[1231, 52, 22]
[1231, 52, 22]
[1231, 52, 22]
[1231, 52, 22]
[1231, 52, 22]
[1231, 52, 22]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = [ [1,3,251], [2], [1231,52,22] ]
new_list = []
for i in list:
    new_list.append(max(i))
print(max(new_list))
```

This will do. This will print only the highest number from the entire list.

Comment: For future readers: This indeed works though if the lists are large or this is executed many times, this approach is slow and uses a lot of memory, as the lists are replicated in an explicit loop. One would be better served to use a comprehension or built-in function that leverages iterators (as shown in my answer below).

Comment: @labroid The solution is sub-optimal but to be fair the lists are not replicated in the loop, only the highest value from each list is appended to a new one.

Comment: Ah yes! You are right - it only replicates, part of the list.  Still something to consider for large lists or intensive loops. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `i` and `j` anywhere in your code. Since you have a nested list you should have nested `max` calls:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 3, 251], [2], [1231, 52, 22]]
>>> max(max(sub_list) for sub_list in my_list)
1231
```

Alternatively you can use a nested list comprehension to flatten the list, then make a single `max` call:

```
>>> max(i for sub_list in my_list for i in sub_list)
1231
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```py
xss = [ [1,3,251], [2], [1231,52,22] ]
result = max(max(xs) for xs in xss)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are very handy functions in itertools for de-nesting. For example:

```
from itertools import chain

list = [ [1,3,251], [2], [1231,52,22] ]

print(max(chain(*list)))
```

So this is a one-line solution (plus an import)